# Overlay two bitmaps and rub out the top one

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I'm having trouble trying to create a screen where I have two bitmaps (one on top of the other so it's totally obscuring the lower one) and "rub out" the top one so it reveals the bottom one under the path of the finger. I realise I may need 3 separate layers (bottom image, top image and then a custom view that handles the finger tracking) but I can't find a method of manipulating the middle layer from the custom view. Can anyone offer some advice on how I might do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the whole thing in one View, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467334/erase-bitmap-parts-using-porterduff-mode) and its answer for more info and links.