# How to program for eraserPaint as on canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-emulator, android-widget

I have implement the Canvas and paint to draw on canvas.
i am able to do the Paint on canvas with different colour.

Now, if there is white plain background then its ok. I am using white color for Eraserand its work fine.
But if there is any image on the background and if i select eraser (as like white colour) then it is being paint of white color on the image.

Instead of that i want is, While i select eraser and if there is any image in background then the eraser should erase the paint and show the image.  . 
So can anybudy help me how to implement it ??
Thanks.

Edited:
I am using below code to Erase the doing paint. But still not able to erase it.

```
case R.id.eraserBtn:
            currentPaint = new Paint();
            currentPaint.setAlpha(0);         
            currentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));         
            currentPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

            //currentPaint.setColor(0x00000000);
            currentPaint.setDither(true);
            currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            break;
```

New Edited:

```
 case R.id.eraserBtn:
            currentPaint = new Paint();
            currentPaint.setAlpha(0);         
            currentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));         
            currentPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

            //currentPaint.setColor(0x00000000);
            currentPaint.setDither(true);
            currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            break;
```

Another Edit:

```
      while (_run){

                try{
                    canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    if(mBitmap == null){
                        mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    }
                    final Canvas c = new Canvas (mBitmap);
                    //canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                    c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                    //canvas.drawColor(mColor);// Edited by Shreyash
                    c.drawColor(mColor);

//                    Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
//                      canvas.drawBitmap (kangoo, 0,  200,null);

//                  works for logo                  
//                  Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
//                  c.drawBitmap (kangoo, 0,  200,null);

                    if(!(DrawingActivity.imagePath==null)){
                        c.drawBitmap(DrawingActivity.mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                    }
                    commandManager.executeAll(c);
                    canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null);

                } finally {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly aware of your code. but `setColor` works for me. But you can try one of the following code though not an exact solution but for your reference...

1. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html
2. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html
3. **Best one** (as I suggest) : http://som-itsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/12/freeware-android-paint.html

Answer (score 2):

You should set setXfermode for the paint object and look into the different PorterDuffModes.

This should prove useful to you:
[Erase bitmap parts using PorterDuff mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467334/erase-bitmap-parts-using-porterduff-mode)

Comment: Please see updated question. Still i am not able to erase the paint.

Comment: use DST_IN, instead of DST_OUT. Also make sure, when creating the bitmap, you're using Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888. Only then setAlpha() will work.

Comment: I have set the value as you have said. But still not getting the sollution.

Comment: post the code where you are creating the bitmap. Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 is absolutely essential.

Comment: Ok Please See another edit for the code where i am creating mBitmap and also draw on it.

Comment: 1) Your mBitmap's size is 1x1. 2) Make sure you're not mixing up the two canvases you have. 3) Make sure you're using currentPaint when drawing on to the canvas.

Comment: Yes i am using currentPaint. And in My application i am using other image as a Background thats why i am using other canvas. So it it possible for that ?

Comment: please tell me what should i have to do to make eraser in My code.