# Android: Clipping and/or PorterDuff Mode to punch "hole" into view in draw() method

Tags: java, android, graphics

I currently have a custom view whose color is set using the following,

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
```

What I would like to do a punch a "hole" in the now red background or essentially fill that hole with a transparent color.  I would also like to invert this as well to my choosing.  If anyone can shed some light on this topic, much would be appreciated. I've looked at this post [erase bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467334/erase-bitmap-parts-using-porterduff-mode) but it seems overkill for what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: The code in the following link should help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665064/canvas-motion-draw-circle/8665396#8665396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Xfermode graphics sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/index.html) from Android.

This [blog post](http://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/) has an example that uses the canvas.drawColor, but on top of an existing bitmap.