# Android canvas - Draw a transparent hole over a rectangle

Tags: android, canvas

I've seen multiple posts about drawing a hole over a bitmap, however that doesn't seem to work when trying to draw over a filled area, such as a rectangle.

For example:

1. I'm drawing a background with `canvas.drawRect()` and `canvas.drawText()`

[image]

2. I'm drawing a red rectangle over the background with `canvas.drawPaint()` or `canvas.drawRect()`

[image]

3. **What I'm trying to achieve**: Draw a circle that will reveal the background (hole)

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Similar questions: [Android canvas - Draw a hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841719/android-canvas-draw-a-hole) & [Erase bitmap parts using PorterDuff mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467334/erase-bitmap-parts-using-porterduff-mode) however the proposed solutions do not work when trying to draw over a rectangle instead of a bitmap. (i.e. I create the background dynamically using `canvas.drawRect()`, `canvas.drawLines()`, etc., I do not have a static bitmap).

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani I've already checked that question, however the OP is drawing a hole over a bitmap, while I'm trying to draw a hole over a canvas dynamic background (lines, rectangles, etc.).

Comment: Can you add an extra layer (an extra View in between)? The bottom layer can be any dynamic drawing and the top layer an overlay with a "hole".

Comment: I ended up creating a new bitmap as an overlay where I draw the background and the hole and it worked. I would prefer to solve that without the need of a bitmap, but it seems that there's no other way. You need to create a new bitmap, link a new canvas to that bitmap, draw on that canvas whatever you want as the background, then draw a hole, then add that bitmap to your initial canvas. If you draw on the initial canvas directly you will end up with a black opaque circle, that's why you need an overlay bitmap. I'll mark it as a duplicate, although I would still prefer a more efficient solution.