# How to set transparent parts/change color of map polygon on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created several polygons over google map which are filled with color

```
Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(opts.strokeColor(Color.WHITE).strokeWidth(2).fillColor(Color.RED));
```

I know how to set transparent whole polygon but is is it possible to set transparent only  parts of it(change color)?
The idea is, when  the user touches the parts of polygon they are set transperent, something similar to this:
[Erase bitmap parts using PorterDuff mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467334/erase-bitmap-parts-using-porterduff-mode)
But this example is used for DrawingViews and bitmaps, not for maps and polygons.

Comment: how about breaking your polygon into smaller polygons so it looks like just one polygon, in reality, many smaller polygons combine into a large one. Then, when user touches a part of the polygon, you simply change the transparency of that smaller polygon.

Comment: I think it will simply kill the performance, since I already have quite a lot of polygons. Besides with so many polygons it won't be possible to calculate coordinates for small ones.