# How can i do mask effect of two images

Tags: android

How can I do this effects with android 
The result
[image: result]

Image 1
[image: image1]

Image 2
[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplishe this by using xfer modes. There is a demostration of all xfer modes in apiDemos example which comes with Android development kit.

Also you can check this example of mine: [Make certain area of bitmap transparent on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch/5439357#5439357)