# ImageView changing image slow in tablet

Tags: android-imageview, touch-event, android

I am writing a keyboard replacement app for Android, and based on the user's touch, a different image is rendered in a specified ImageView. I am running into an issue with two things:

**1)** With the tablet, I can move my finger quicker, so the `onTouch` method I am using is losing touch events. For instance, in a quick circle, my touch pattern looks like this:

```
x: 590.0 y: 178.0
x: 488.0 y: 172.0
x: 233.0 y: 416.0
x: 394.0 y: 451.0
x: 575.0 y: 199.0
x: 450.0 y: 170.0
x: 341.0 y: 193.0
```

(using Logcat and event.getX(), event.getY())

Is there a better way track events with a tablet to pick up more events?

**2)** The changing image in the imageview renders slower than in the phone app. Is there a way to fix this, or is it a limitation of the tablet? I change the imageview by:

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a custom view and onTouch event. You would have to pre-load all your buttons states as bitmaps.

See this example: [Make certain area of bitmap transparent on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch/5439357#5439357)

Answer (score 0):

I get much better performance pre-decoding it via `BitmapFactory`, which should look something like this (untested):

```
myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myImageView.getContext().getResources(),R.res.drawable.my_image);
//later
myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```