# Android bitmap processing in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch), but it's too slow for a smooth live wallpaper. Is it possible to do the same with OpenGL, which should be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible with OpenGL. You would load your two textures and then decide which to show on a per pixel basis using a fragment shader.  The actual OpenGL part wont be too complicated as your are effectleiy just drawing a screen aligned quad.  For an idea of how to write the shaders i'd look [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/multi-texture/).

As for which would be faster its hard to say, although i'd think OpengGL would be faster.

Comment: You wouldn't need a mask texture in this approach, You would just pass the position of the users touch to the shader and make all of the pixels within a certain radius of that point transparent in the fragment shader.