# Make part of image transparent on Touch

Tags: android, image-processing, android-imageview, android-image

I have a layout with the follwoing:

`Framelayout` with two `ImageView`s. Each `ImageView` has one image.

What I am trying to acheive is: on touch on the `ImageView`, the touch area should become **transparent** and show the image below.

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rect" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/i2" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So basically on touch on `imageView2` the touch area should show the image from `imageView1`.

I just need some pointers or references.

Comment: I think you will have to manually change alpha levels on image, based on touch location.

Comment: @mata any reference examples ?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch

Comment: @mata i did its a excellent solution but in that example the answer is drawing images dyanmically using onDraw, whereas i have a xml layout with imageviews in which i want to apply the effect

Comment: solved it , just learnt about custom views , implemented the code in the link @mata posted in a custom view and then used that custom view in my layout , cheers

Answer (score 0):

use this code inside your TouchListener

```
ImageView view1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
view1.setZOrderOnTop(true);    // necessary
SurfaceHolder sfhTrackHolder = view1.getHolder();
sfhTrackHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: i am getting the method setZOrderOnTop(boolean) is undefined for the type ImageView

Answer (score 0):

First get your local var fo the img

```
ImageView myImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
```

Make sure you have a onClickListener on the myImage2, then:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.imageview2) {
          myImage2.setAlpha((float) 0.55); //value: [0-1]. Where 0 is fully transparent .and 1 is fully opaque
    }
```

Comment: This makes whole image transparent, not touch area only.

Comment: So you only where the user "touches", like a area?