# On touch image in canvas make transparent to see below image

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, invalidation

I am trying for small application . In that I have two Image bitmap on top of each other which is draw on canvas , on touch I need to make above image bitmap transparent as I touch the canvas screen so I can see the below Image. I also refers this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch)

but it showing the only black circle not below image. I tested it on kitkat OS that 4.4.2.

Please help me, Thanx in Advance .....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

In AndroidManifest for application:
`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>`

Or if you draw in `View`'s `onDraw` method, you can do for this view:
`view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

More information you can read in documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

Hope it helps