# Add OverlayView on ImageView in Android at particular X-Y Co-ordinate

Tags: android, overlay, android-custom-view, pinchzoom, touchimageview

I have **back side TouchImageview**, which having **zoom in/out** functionality, I am setting up **bitmap** on **ImageView**, the size of Bitmap is **w-h (2100 x 2900)**, I have **particular X-Y co-ordinate**, now I want to **add Overlay** view at **same co-ordinate as per imageview's X-Y co-ordinate**, the background imageview should be touchable.

Can you please let me know solution for the same.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: To make the transparency circle through the ImageView looks like it requires use of the canvas. You can make it wherever you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch

Comment: @CmosBattery, thanks for reply, but I do not need to touch image, x-y co ordinates are predefined. Thanks

Comment: @HirenPatel Hi Hiren. I need one help regarding this

Comment: @Piyush, yes please.

Comment: @HirenPatel Tare aa working che ? Proper ?? Hoy to mane apk share karne check karvi che. Kem k mare crop type nu j che so . Pls. And if same as i need then can you pls share code ? And jetla part no screenshot le che etla no j bitmap proper male che cropped ??

Comment: @Piyush, As of now I don't have source code. But one of the alternative you can find https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2lY08LUSUMMQlRKNVNjX3h6REk/view

Comment: I have already checked that. But i can't get proper from it. Do u have apk file ? From where i can check ?

Comment: @Piyush, No man. Don't have. I had founded some other solution for this. Let me check if it available or not.

Comment: @HirenPatel Okay. Pls check and let me know if u can. Pls

Comment: @HirenPatel Hi. Have you found alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an iOS developer, but can be answer to your question, as I'm sure that these things are also possible in Android ! ;)

You can follow these steps:

1. Don’t make any change in your current flow.
2. Add overlay view the way you want.
3. Take screenshot of the back image view which are showing location, may be of particular size (or the exact size of circle on overlay).
4. Show that captured screenshot (image) at circle view position (you can have an another image view for that).
5. Zoom that image view (From Step.4)
6. You are done!

Goodluck.